# ctime, xmemory, xstring, stdexcept etc. errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm getting the above errors on a plain C++ Console project in Visual Studio. I'm unsure why this is occuring but it happens in every project I have now and I'm unsure as to what is causing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am compiling in x86 and I have tried the Debug and Release versions and that doesn't help with the issue.

This error randomly appeared in a previous project of mine, I was using the sqlite3 package and had no issues then later in the project these errors appeared so I don't believe that could have caused the issue but I removed the sqlite3 package and it didn't solve the issue so I made a brand new project with the code below and I still get the same errors.

**Current code:**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

**Errors:**

```
> 1>Test.cpp
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory(1200,45):
> error C3646: 'thrown': unknown override specifier
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory(1200,51):
> error C2059: syntax error: ':'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory(1200,51):
> error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding ':'; skipping apparent
> function body
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory(1201,23):
> error C3876: hexadecimal floating literal requires an exponent
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory(1206,55):
> error C3254: 'std::_Iterator_base12': class contains explicit override
> '_Orphan_all' but does not derive from an interface that contains the
> function declaration
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory(1206,55):
> error C2838: '_Orphan_all': illegal qualified name in member
> declaration
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory(1220,94):
> error C3254: 'std::_Iterator_base12': class contains explicit override
> '_Swap_proxy_and_iterators' but does not derive from an interface that
> contains the function declaration
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory(1220,94):
> error C2838: '_Swap_proxy_and_iterators': illegal qualified name in
> member declaration
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory(1848,28):
> error C2178: 'std::_Iterator_base12::_Use_memset_value_construct_v'
> cannot be declared with 'constexpr' specifier
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory(1848,28):
> error C3376: 'std::_Iterator_base12::_Use_memset_value_construct_v':
> only static data member templates are allowed
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory(2107,32):
> error C2039: 'remove_if': is not a member of 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory(25):
> message : see declaration of 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory(2107,32):
> message : This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function
> '_Container::size_type
> std::_Iterator_base12::_Erase_remove_if(_Container &,_Pr)'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xstring(33,1):
> error C2059: syntax error: 'namespace'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xstring(33,1):
> error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory(1230,1):
> error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'std::_Iterator_base12 *' to
> 'const std::_Container_base12 *'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory(1230,29):
> message : Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires
> reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xstring(33,1):
> error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(26,25):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(26,38):
> error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(26,60):
> error C2065: '_Message': undeclared identifier
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(43,26):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(43,39):
> error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(43,61):
> error C2065: '_Message': undeclared identifier
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(43,60):
> error C2512: 'std::std::logic_error::logic_error': no appropriate
> default constructor available
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(60,30):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(60,43):
> error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(60,65):
> error C2065: '_Message': undeclared identifier
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(60,64):
> error C2512: 'std::std::logic_error::logic_error': no appropriate
> default constructor available
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(77,26):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(77,39):
> error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(77,61):
> error C2065: '_Message': undeclared identifier
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(77,60):
> error C2512: 'std::std::logic_error::logic_error': no appropriate
> default constructor available
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(94,26):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(94,39):
> error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(94,61):
> error C2065: '_Message': undeclared identifier
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(94,60):
> error C2512: 'std::std::logic_error::logic_error': no appropriate
> default constructor available
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(111,27):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(111,40):
> error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(111,62):
> error C2065: '_Message': undeclared identifier
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(128,28):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(128,41):
> error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(128,63):
> error C2065: '_Message': undeclared identifier
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(128,62):
> error C2512: 'std::std::runtime_error::runtime_error': no appropriate
> default constructor available
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(145,29):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(145,42):
> error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(145,64):
> error C2065: '_Message': undeclared identifier
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(145,63):
> error C2512: 'std::std::runtime_error::runtime_error': no appropriate
> default constructor available
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(162,25):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(162,38):
> error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(162,60):
> error C2065: '_Message': undeclared identifier
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\stdexcept(162,59):
> error C2512: 'std::std::runtime_error::runtime_error': no appropriate
> default constructor available
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\ctime(22,13):
> error C2039: 'clock_t': is not a member of '`global namespace''
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\ctime(22,1):
> error C2873: 'clock_t': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\ctime(26,13):
> error C2039: 'asctime': is not a member of '`global namespace''
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\ctime(26,1):
> error C2873: 'asctime': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\ctime(27,13):
> error C2039: 'clock': is not a member of '`global namespace''
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\ctime(27,1):
> error C2873: 'clock': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\ctime(28,13):
> error C2039: 'ctime': is not a member of '`global namespace''
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\ctime(28,1):
> error C2873: 'ctime': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\ctime(29,13):
> error C2039: 'difftime': is not a member of '`global namespace''
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\ctime(29,1):
> error C2873: 'difftime': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\ctime(30,13):
> error C2039: 'gmtime': is not a member of '`global namespace''
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\ctime(30,1):
> error C2873: 'gmtime': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\ctime(31,13):
> error C2039: 'localtime': is not a member of '`global namespace''
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\ctime(31,1):
> error C2873: 'localtime': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\ctime(32,13):
> error C2039: 'mktime': is not a member of '`global namespace''
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\ctime(32,1):
> error C2873: 'mktime': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\ctime(33,13):
> error C2039: 'strftime': is not a member of '`global namespace''
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\ctime(33,1):
> error C2873: 'strftime': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\ctime(34,13):
> error C2039: 'time': is not a member of '`global namespace''
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\ctime(34,1):
> error C2873: 'time': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\atomic(1017,14):
> error C2039: 'atomic_thread_fence': is not a member of 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory(25):
> message : see declaration of 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\atomic(1144):
> message : see reference to class template instantiation
> 'std::std::_Atomic_storage<_Ty,8>' being compiled
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\atomic(2503,10):
> error C2039: 'atomic_store_explicit': is not a member of 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory(25):
> message : see declaration of 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\atomic(2509,10):
> error C2039: 'atomic_store_explicit': is not a member of 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory(25):
> message : see declaration of 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(81,31):
> error C3646: 'message': unknown override specifier
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(81,39):
> error C2062: type 'int' unexpected
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(81,61):
> error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(159,23):
> error C3646: 'message': unknown override specifier
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(159,30):
> error C2059: syntax error: '('
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(159,39):
> error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent
> function body
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(124,53):
> error C2039: 'system_category': is not a member of 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory(25):
> message : see declaration of 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(146,24):
> error C2039: 'system_category': is not a member of 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory(25):
> message : see declaration of 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(239,23):
> error C3646: 'message': unknown override specifier
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(239,30):
> error C2059: syntax error: '('
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(239,39):
> error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent
> function body
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(206,58):
> error C2039: 'generic_category': is not a member of 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory(25):
> message : see declaration of 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(228,24):
> error C2039: 'generic_category': is not a member of 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory(25):
> message : see declaration of 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(345,54):
> error C2039: 'generic_category': is not a member of 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory(25):
> message : see declaration of 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(349,54):
> error C2039: 'iostream_category': is not a member of 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory(25):
> message : see declaration of 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(354,59):
> error C2039: 'generic_category': is not a member of 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory(25):
> message : see declaration of 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(358,59):
> error C2039: 'iostream_category': is not a member of 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory(25):
> message : see declaration of 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(370,2):
> error C2888: 'std::hash<std::std::error_code>': symbol cannot be
> defined within namespace 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(380,2):
> error C2888: 'std::hash<std::std::error_condition>': symbol cannot be
> defined within namespace 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(385,19):
> error C3646: '_Makestr': unknown override specifier
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(385,28):
> error C2275: 'std::std::error_code': illegal use of this type as an
> expression
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(122):
> message : see declaration of 'std::std::error_code'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(385,39):
> error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_Errcode'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(385,66):
> error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent
> function body
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(395,18):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(395,52):
> error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(396,44):
> error C2065: '_Message': undeclared identifier
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(396,25):
> error C3861: '_Makestr': identifier not found
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(408,17):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(408,51):
> error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(414,17):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(414,74):
> error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(406,17):
> error C2664:
> 'std::std::_System_error::_System_error(std::std::error_code,const
> int)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'const char [1]' to 'const int'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(406,59):
> message : There is no context in which this conversion is possible
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(395,5):
> message : see declaration of 'std::std::_System_error::_System_error'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(408,83):
> error C2065: '_Message': undeclared identifier
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(410,17):
> error C2664:
> 'std::std::_System_error::_System_error(std::std::error_code,const
> int)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'const char *' to 'const int'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(410,81):
> message : There is no context in which this conversion is possible
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(395,5):
> message : see declaration of 'std::std::_System_error::_System_error'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(412,17):
> error C2664:
> 'std::std::_System_error::_System_error(std::std::error_code,const
> int)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'const char [1]' to 'const int'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(412,102):
> message : There is no context in which this conversion is possible
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(395,5):
> message : see declaration of 'std::std::_System_error::_System_error'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(415,49):
> error C2065: '_Message': undeclared identifier
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(418,18):
> error C2664:
> 'std::std::_System_error::_System_error(std::std::error_code,const
> int)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'const char *' to 'const int'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(418,49):
> message : There is no context in which this conversion is possible
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(395,5):
> message : see declaration of 'std::std::_System_error::_System_error'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(433,5):
> error C2039: 'make_error_code': is not a member of 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xmemory(25):
> message : see declaration of 'std'
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(462,31):
> error C3646: 'message': unknown override specifier
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(462,39):
> error C2062: type 'int' unexpected
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(462,68):
> error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent
> function body
>     1>E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(462,68):
> fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
>     1>Done building project "Test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

Comment: `'thrown': unknown override specifier` is weird. The keyword is `throw`. I suspect that an extra character somehow accidentally was typed into the standard header. Try repairing your Visual Studio installation.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I just tried reparing using the installer and opened the plain console project and I still get 118 errors.

Comment: What C++ version? Any non-default compiler options? Also, open the `xmemory` file printed in the error message at line 1200: What does it say?

Comment: I suggest you try to repair or reinstall VS.

Comment: I tried reparing and reinstalling but that didn't seem to solve the issue. I ended up using 'Reset this PC' in Windows Settings to reinstall Window and I'm not longer having the above issue, I'm still unsure to what the actual issue was though.